# What causes iOS games to be added to a user's games connections?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, connection, prime31

I'm developing an iOS game in Unity using the Prime31 Social Networking plugin to handle Facebook integration. Everything seems to be working; posting to walls on behalf of the app, graph requests, etc. However the app isn't being added to the user's games connections, ie. when I go to https://graph.facebook.com/myname/games?access_token=whatever it returns an empty set on my testing account. I know that other apps using the same engine and plugins are somehow able to get a connection on the user that returns this information about the game when querying "games" through the link above:

```
{

   "data": [

      {
         "name": "My Game",

         "category": "Games/toys",

         "id": "XXXXXXXXX",

        "created_time": "XXXXXXXXXX"

      }
   ],

   "paging": {
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
   }
}
```

Could I be missing something in the app setup, am I supposed to post this info myself to the user's game connections, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah... this connection is not when you have installed an app of type 'Games', but when you have liked a Page which was created as a 'Brand or Product' of type 'Games/Toys'.

In other words, it is a peer of the movies, music, television connections, rather than anything to do with the apps a user has authenticated with.

Of course you can create a Page to go with your app. Get people to like it to appear in this enumeration for them.